# Showing 404 even when blocked

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to block a file that is accessed several times a day.

Therefore I tried to block it in .htaccess to avoid any php execution in WordPress:

```
<Files "/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

But still, WordPress is working and showing a 404 page. How can I just block this single file so WordPress is not displaying a 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ - [F]
```

F = forbidden

Comment: I tried it, takes a lot longer to load and then wordpress kicks in again. :-(

Comment: @Screenload did you put this _before_ the existing WP rewrite configuration, or after it?

Comment: @CBroe before it

Comment: So when you say WP shows its 404 page, then this is not an actually _existing_ file to begin with, yes?

Comment: That's true, maybe that's the issue here?

Comment: I created the file and WordPress is showing the error page, but if I just remove the code from the .htaccess the empty file is shown, wich also solves my problem because no php execution is stressing the server